# svg filter changes on leaflet 'zoom'

Tags: svg, leaflet, svg-filters

I am trying to add some filters to some svg path's in Leaflet, in order to show different "states" of an object, to alert the end user that something is wrong with that specific object.

The issue I am having is the filter changes on zoom, when zoomed out (path gets smaller) the "glow" stays the same size (gets bigger relative to the path), I need it to stay the same relative to the path and not the display. see below images for example.

[image: zoomed out]

[image: zoomed in]

This is my filter:

```
    <filter id='polygonStatus-endOfLife' filterRes="10 10" x="-20%" y="-20%" width="140%" height="140%"
            filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" primitiveUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="linearRGB">
        <feComposite in="SourceAlpha" in2="SourceAlpha" operator="arithmetic" k1="0" k2="8" k3="-0.5" k4="-0.5" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" result="composite"/>
        <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0
            0 1 0 0 0
            0 0 1 0 0
            0 0 0 1 0" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" in="composite" result="colormatrix1"/>
        <feMorphology operator="dilate" radius="10 10" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" in="colormatrix1" result="morphology1"/>
        <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="10 10" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" in="morphology1" edgeMode="none" result="blur2"/>
        <feComposite in="blur2" in2="composite" operator="out" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" result="composite2"/>
        <feMerge x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" result="merge">
            <feMergeNode in="composite2"/>
            <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
        </feMerge>
    </filter>
```

I would like it closer to how it looks on the "zoomed in" image, more subtle. i basicly need it to act as if your resizing a bitmap image (resize the second screenshot to smaller to see what I mean)

Comment: This can't be the correct filter - this filter is just adding 50% brightness to a 50% SourceAlpha and then applying an identity feColorMatrix (which does nothing). Glows are usually generated by a feGaussianBlur - which must be somewhere else (maybe applied to a g wrapper element?)

Comment: @MichaelMullany I apologize, looks like I either failed to paste the hole filter or it got cut off, have updated the question with full filter.

Comment: @MichaelMullany I have found a hacky solution that will work for now. on 'zoomend' I am using jQuery to change the 'radius' of the morph and 'dilate' of the blur. ended up using the zoom level and squaring it, then dividing by 50 to get the number for both, produces a good effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come up with a solution that works. Its probably not the best solution but until i find a better one it will have to do.

I am using jQuery to change the stdDeviation and radius on zoom level change as follows:

```
map.on('zoomend', function(){
    var size = (Math.pow(map.getZoom(),2) / 50);
    $('#svgFilters feMorphology').attr('radius', size);
    $('#svgFilters feGaussianBlur').attr('stdDeviation', size);
});
```

I am using the zoom level squared then divided by 50 to get a good looking glow that gets smaller when zooming out, it gets smaller faster than the path itself which for my applications looks better.

Answer (score 1):

This is an unusual way to add a glow - since it looks like you're drawing the glow separately and then drawing the shape on top? Normally you add a glow directly to a shape via a filter.

If you want a glow that scales with the shape and is applied directly to the shape, then you should try something a bit different using feGaussianBlur and primitiveUnits="objectBoundingBox". Something like:

```
<filter id="dropshadow" primitiveUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="-20%" y="-20%" width="140%" height="140%">
<feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="0.05"/>
<feComposite operator="over" in="SourceGraphic"/>
</filter>
```

Comment: I cannot add a blur directly as the object is partially transparent and you need to be able to see behind the item (it also looks weird with the blur behind it.) so I am creating the blur separate then 'cutting out' the original shape from the blur, then overlaying it. I tried changing primitiveUnits to objectBoundingBox but it causes massive performance issues (from 50+fps down to about 2fps)

Comment: You can do dropshadows on partially transparent shapes by boosting the transparency with either an feColorMatrix or a feComponentTransfer/feFuncA and then using feComposite/out. But the perf. issues seem like a killer.